# Is there any other method to filter away the empty space in excel?

Tags: excel, filter, office365, compatibility

[image]
Hi all,

I'm thinking of a way to filter away the empty space in column C so that I can get the desired output exactly the same as the one in column H. I only can figure out using `filter` function but it seems like only works if the user subscribe for office 365, otherwise it will have compatibility issue. Is there any other way to do it instead of using `filter` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Aggregate()` function to filter data based on condition. Try-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$4:$C$31,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($C$4:$C$31)-ROW($C$3))/($C$4:$C$31<>""),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

[image]

If your excel version is older than `Excel2013` then use <kbd>CSE</kbd> entry below formula.

```
=INDEX($C$4:$C$31,SMALL(IF($C$4:$C$31<>"",ROW($C$4:$C$31)-ROW($C$3),""),ROW(1:1)))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

Comment: Jus to confirm that if I want the formula to works for the entire column C then I need to change `$C$31` to something like `$C$10000` right?

Comment: @Elvis You are right. You need to change this both in index and aggregate.

Comment: I found out that if I use this formula, it will assume the empty cells have a value bigger than 1. This is because when I check `IF(cell>0,1,0)`, it shows `1` to me although the cell is blank. This will affect my other calculation. Is there any method to avoid that?

Comment: @Elvis No. It will just check `$C$4:$C$31<>""` if a cell is blank or not.